# What is the correct method for training NLP models with augmented data?

Tags: dataset, natural-language, transfer-learning, data-augmentation

I have a very small dataset (~50 rows) for a text classification problem. I found some open source data that's similar to the problem I'm trying to solve.

Should I...

1. Train the (BERT) model on the open data, then fine-tune again on the original (small) dataset.
2. Combine the two datasets and fine tune the entire thing (also on BERT).

Also, what should be my validation/hold-out set be in either case?

Answer (score 1):

With only 50 samples, I think there is very little one can do. I would suggest training BERT on the "open data" and treating the 50 samples as our hold-out set. Using 50 samples to fine-tuning millions of model parameters is unrealistic. *Maybe* and depending on the exact task and training data, augmentation could work but only if the samples are quite long and we could split them in some way.

I would advise against combining the two datasets together as this precludes us from using the only "real-world" data we have for testing; we might want to consider synthesizing some data from our real data to fine-tune BERT further but that is a bit of a slippery slope regarding [leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leakage_(machine_learning)). Ultimately the whole idea is that BERT is pre-trained on such a large amount of data that it already "knows" a lot of information about languages so fine-tuning it at the "open data" should be adequate. So... Option 3. "*Original data for hold-out/testing and open data for training/fine-tuning*".